# Are concurrent reads possible in Netty 4?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

From [these notes](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/New-and-noteworthy-in-4.x):

> Netty will never call a `ChannelHandler`'s methods concurrently, unless the `ChannelHandler` is annotated with `@Sharable`. This is regardless of the type of handler methods - inbound, outbound, or life cycle event handler methods.

I have no problem with that. My question is, however, if it is possible for two different messages to be read/processed from the same channel at the same time, at different stages of the pipeline.

For instance, consider the following pipeline (`ChannelInboundHandler`s only):

```
+-----------+
| Handler 2 |
+-----------+
      ^
      |
+-----------+
| Handler 1 |
+-----------+
      ^
      |
+-----------+
| I/O read  |
+-----------+
```

I understand that only one thread, at most, may be calling the methods from `Handler 1`, unless it is `Sharable`. But, can a thread be processing a message in `Handler 2` while another thread is processing a message **for the same channel** in `Handler 1`? Or is the channel selected only when the current message reaches the end of the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you have added one of the ChannelHandler to the pipeline with a EventExecutorGroup passed in. If you not use one everything will just handled by the EventLoop and so one Thread.